# Ubuntu 18.04 (Unity) Terminal shortcut not working

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04

So I have a almost fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed unity as DE (having both gnome and unity installed atm) and any combination of keys I put in the terminal shorcut just doesn't work.

I've logged into gnome and changed the shorcut to something random and it seemed to have fixed the problem when logged in unity, buy after a few reboots it just stops working again.

Comment: Do other keyboard shortcuts work?

Comment: Did you install the `ubuntu-unity.desktop` package?If not I suggest you do so. Note that while unity can run from gdm3 lightdm is better.

Comment: @Emily yes the other shortcuts work, for example I can move from workspaces.

Comment: @doug I installed using that package.

Comment: hmm, I use unity in 18.04 & all is well. You could try this, reboot, log into unity session. Open home folder > `.config/dconf` folder, inside will be a file named `user` . (.config is a hidden folder, ctrl+h if you don't see it).  Either delete the file or rename to user.bak  (I'd just delete).  Then immediately reboot & log into unity, see if it works.  If so see what happens in a gnome session (- I'm not a big fan of mixing sessions..